# Magento, what could cause $model->load($id) to fail?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I wrote a module for magento, and tested in my localhost. It was working like a charm.

But after uploading to a server, when I try to load a product with the following code:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
```

the code execution stops. No exception.log generated. no output to browser.

By outputing to system.log i was able to verify a correct id was being used, and there is a product with that id in the store.

this load method is used by the default catalog/product controllers and works, but its not working in my module.

## edit:

I've debbuged and got it to output something to system.log.

```
2013-09-02T20:49:33+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 3 passed to Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::_canUpdateAttribute() must be an array, null given, called in /home/next/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php on line 545 and defined  in /home/next/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 1254
2013-09-02T20:49:33+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists() [<a href='function.array-key-exists'>function.array-key-exists</a>]: The second argument should be either an array or an object  in /home/next/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 1256
```

I dont think that was originated in my module, since i uploaded it to a clean store and it was working like it should. That store has almost 15 modules installed and one of them is probably overriding something that shouldn't, or maybe the store owner changed something in original magento source code.

I recommended to disable module by module so he can discover what module is causing the problem and revert all possible changes in original source code, but i'm not sure if the store owner will be able to do that.

Isnt there any way i can test current magento installation to be sure my module will work with no conflict with other pre-installed modules??

Comment: What do you mean "its not working in my model"? Are you rewriting `catalog/product`?

Comment: mistype. It should be "module", not model.

Comment: Ah, that happens a lot for ESL folk. You should try to talk with Ukrainian core devs about models in modules!

Answer (score 2):

PHP almost never "just stops" without producing an error.  Temporarily edit `index.php` such that

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

and (or set the `MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE` flag to true in your web server)

```
if (true || isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

Additionally, check your **php error log** for any error produced when you run your code.